# Progressive web app implementation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, progressive-web-apps

I'm researching progressive web apps, and i was wondering if it's possible to integrate this technology with existing ASP.NET MVC web applications.

I don't find any example of this integration, only in combination of javascript frameworks that render HTML like angular, knockout etc.

Also, is it possible to host a progressive web app on IIS or are you limited to an apache web server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After testing, I was successful at implementing the functionality by adding the service worker and manifest to a ASP.NET MVC application. Since the view (HTML) gets rendered in the back-end, it's only possible to cache a static version of your web application. So preferable you should use angular etc to generate your HTML.

A progressive web app works on IIS and Apache web server.

Comment: Nice!! I got it working too..