# Aspx Support PWA or Not

Tags: c#, asp.net, progressive-web-apps

Are there any way to do a project using pwa concept in ASPX page? I am using HTML with PWA, it was working fine but I moved into the ASP .NET. It doesn't work anymore and the JSON file is not loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will maybe found this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45995057/progressive-web-app-implementation-in-asp-net-mvc) useful.

> After testing, i was successful at implementing the functionality by
>   adding the serviceworker and manifest to a ASP.NET MVC application.
>   Since the view (HTML) gets rendered in the backend, it's only possible
>   to cache an static version of your web application. So preferable you
>   should use angular etc to generate your HTML.
>
> A progressive web app works on IIS and apache web server.

Answer (score 1):

progressive web app is a general concept. It has nothing to do with your web server. Please give more details about your code architecture etc
you can also use swtoolbox plugin for handing client side caching 
mybe your problem is client-side caching. however PWA concepts are as follows, neither of them has nothing to do with web server type

Progressive - Works for every user regardless of their browser

Responsive - The app works on any form factor whether it's desktop, mobile, or tablet.

Connectivity-independent - Allows the user to use the web app even if it's offline.

Native Look-and-feel - Acts and feels like a native application, but is strictly web-based.

Safe - Always served up to the client through HTTPS.

Discoverable - Even though it's an "application," it can be indexed into a search engine.

Re-engageable - Allows re-engagement through features like push notifications.

Zero-Deploy hassle - Allows users to add the web app onto their home screen without the issues with app stores.

Link-friendly - Allows you to reshare using a Url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes finally I able to accomplish this. PWA now works not only on ASP.NET webform but On any framework.

https://github.com/cpbenipal/PWA_Aspx